# Block validation process

Tags: blockchain, block

Can some one explain how the block validation is done in blockchain based system with suitable example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block Validation: who does it? How much it costs? And is it present in all protocols?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80882/block-validation-who-does-it-how-much-it-costs-and-is-it-present-in-all-proto)  ... See [similar questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=block+validation+is%3Aq)

Comment: There are a lot of steps to validation, you can follow the process at the following code in a Bitcoin Core node: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ed9a2a37c1878ba6b75c39b7cb263dc16c52a295/src/validation.cpp#L3027